# How to add C++ style multi-line comment in algorithmic Latex

Tags: comments, algorithmic

I am using `algorithmic` to write a pseudocode in Latex. I wish to add both single(`//`) and multiple(`/**/`) lines comment in my code.

```
\Procedure{Foo}{$x$}
   \State Set $a\gets b+c$  \LONGCOMMENT{this is a comment broken over b+c and b-c lines} 
   \State Set $d\gets b-c$
```

I want the comment in `\LONGCOMMENT` to appear for both the lines starting with `/*` and ending with `*/` i.e

```
procedure Foo(x)
  Set a <- b+c     /*this is a comment broken 
  Set a <- b-c      over b+c and b-c lines*/
```

Comment: As always on this site, please post full minimal examples, not sniplets. Makes it a **lot** easier to test the code in your question